# scala - extract substring based on special characters

Tags: regex, scala

I have to fetch First name, Middle and Last name from String based on special characters.

First name condition - if name_str contains comma(",")  and ends with space+any single character+period(".")

For example:
name_str - `SMITH, ANNE MARIE J.`
Then First name - `ANNE MARIE`

Middle name condition - if name_str contains comma(",")  and ends with space+any single character+period(".")
Then take the substring single character before "." until space

For example:
name_str - `SMITH, ANNE MARIE J.`
Then Middle name - `J.`

Last name - `SMITH`

I tried below code to get First name, need to add more condition to check if name_str ends with Space+any Character+period(".")

```
if (",.".forall(name_str.contains(,)))
  name_str.substring(name_str.indexOf(",") + 1, name_str.indexOf(" ")).trim
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Comment: What have you tried? Can you give more details about your problem?

Comment: @gianlucaaguzzi - Just added condition that I tried in Spark transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a simple regex for each of the name formats that you're expected to parse.

```
val nameRE1 = "([^,]+),(.+) (.\\.)".r
val nameRE2 = "([^,]+),(.+)".r
val nameRE3 = "(.+) (.\\.) (.+)".r
val nameRE4 = "([^,]+) (.+)".r

List( "SMITH, ANNE MARIE J."
    , "Michael J. Fox"
    , "Van Halen, Eddie"
    , "Jo Blow"
    ).map{
  case nameRE1(ln, fn, mi) => List(fn.strip, mi, ln.strip)
  case nameRE2(ln, fn)     => List(fn.strip, "", ln.strip)
  case nameRE3(fn, mi, ln) => List(fn.strip, mi, ln.strip)
  case nameRE4(fn, ln)     => List(fn.strip, "", ln.strip)
  case nameX               => List(nameX)
}
//res0: List[List[String]] = List(List(ANNE MARIE, J., SMITH)
//                              , List(Michael, J., Fox)
//                              , List(Eddie, "", Van Halen)
//                              , List(Jo, "", Blow))
```

Answer (score 1):

Matching names can be really difficult. For the description in your question, you might use a broad pattern that approaches the given format as names can contain a lot of characters.

It matches the lastname part before the comma, the firstname part after the comma and before the single char dot pattern at the end.

```
^([^\s,][^,]*),\h*([^\s,].*?)\h+([^\s.]\.(?:[^\s.]\.)*)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\s,][^,]*` Match a single non whitespace char except for a comma, followed by matching any char except a comma
- `)` Close group 1
- `,\h*` Match a comma and optional spaces
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[^\s,].*?` Match a single non whitespace char except for a comma
    `)` Close group 2
- `\h+` Match 1+ spaces
- `(` Capture **group 3**

  - `[^\s.]\.` Match a single non whitespace char except for a dot, then match a dot
  - `(?:[^\s.]\.)*` Optionally repeat the same in case of multiple single characters followed by a dot
- `)` Close group 3
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s4OoQo/1) or a [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/M1VUZG)

```
val s = "SMITH, ANNE MARIE J."
val regex =
  """^([^\s,][^,]*),\h*([^\s,].*?)\h+([^\s.]\.(?:[^\s.]\.)*)$"""
    .r("lastname", "firstname", "middlename")

regex.findFirstMatchIn(s) match {
  case Some(m) => println(
    s"Lastname: ${m.group("lastname")}, " +
      s"Firstname: ${m.group("firstname")}, " +
      s"Middlename: ${m.group("middlename")}"
  )
  case None => println("No match.")
}
```

Output

```
Lastname: SMITH, Firstname: ANNE MARIE, Middlename: J.
```